# Change iframe from inside

Tags: javascript, html, perl, iframe

I am trying to change the content of an iframe from inside the iframe.

Perl/backend:

```
my $doc = `curl -k 'http://localhost/givemehtml`;
$doc =~ s|</script|</scr/ipt|g;
$form .=  qq|<script>document.location='data:text/html;charset:utf-8,' + '$doc'; </script>|;
```

`$form` is all of the html in the iframe, which has default content (inserted into `$form` earlier), which I want to change with the script.

With my code above the iframe doesn't change content. How do I fix this?

Comment: So why are you changing `document.location`? If you want to change the documents *content* use the DOM or `document.write()` ...

Comment: @m02ph3u5 What do you mean by "use the DOM"? Could you show how you would do this?

Comment: What do you want to change?

Comment: It is unclear what you're asking for. The page inside the iframe shall change it's contents? Depending on what? The page inside the iframe doesn't care that it's inside an iframe.

Answer (score 1):

Let's call *Outside* the page that loads the iframe tag, and let's call *Inside* the cotent whitin the iframe.

*Outside* can control *Inside*
*Inside* can't control *Outside* for security reasons

In order for *Inside* to speak with *Outside* it must be server-side. *Inside* talks to the server via AJAX (among others methods), and *Outside* may retrieve that information.

If you want *Inside* to change its location (http://localhost/givemehtml), you may use:

```
window.location.href = 'http://localhost/anotherhtml'
```